# How to run automatically Tailwindcss when the PHP project opens on VS?

Tags: php, css, tailwind-css

I would like to ask you how to start automatically tailwindcss framework when the PHP project opens on Visual Studio. I'll explain better: first of all i have create a empty directory for my PHP projec in "C:/xampp/htdocs/project_PHP",afterwards i have follow the installation guide of TailwindCSS from the official website ([Installation Guide](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation)).Next,I created a php file ("index.php") to tested the framework, and all works correctly. The main problem is that: every time I close and open the project from VS, i have to run this command everytime to "start" tailwindcss: '`npx tailwindcss -i input.css -o style.css --watch`'. So far I have only been able to start tailwindcss using the `npm run build` command and setting the script in "package.json".[image: image of script npm run build].

Does anyone know if there is a way to start tailwind automatically when opening the project on VS without entering scripts in the terminal?

Thanks in advance everyone for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to go in Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > PHP or something similar to your project. And select Auto build and refresh browser after saving changes in Auto build and refresh option ?

I know this works for ASP .NET projects. (This will only work if run without debugging though)

Comment: I try to find in "Settings" some keyword like 'build', 'auto build' and 'php', but i can't found anything to solve my problem.